# Show that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ satisfies ascending chain condition for principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

I have got this question from my friend now he is at the beginning of algebra. I can prove this using $\Bbb Z[x]$ Noetherian and so is its quotient but it uses techniques of field extension(quotients) and Noetherian domain. He is just learning PID, UFD, ACCP and all so is there any direct technique starting that $\langle a_1\rangle\subseteq \langle a_2\rangle \subseteq \cdots $ then $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \langle a_i\rangle $ is an ideal and then using structure of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ I can prove that it is a principal ideal.

Comment: Can you not use the fact that any non-zero ideal, principal or not, has a finite index as an additive subgroup, and hence the chain can lower the index only finitely many times?

Comment: I can use it and it seems interesting. Can you please give me that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fact 1.** If $\langle a\rangle\subseteq \langle b\rangle$, then $b|a$. This is clear, and holds in any ring.

Define $N\colon\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\to\mathbb{Z}$ by $N(a+b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2+5b^2$. Then $N$ is multiplicative, so if $a|b$, then $N(a)|N(b)$.

**Fact 2.** The only units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are $1$ and $-1$. Indeed, if $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is a unit, then $a^2+5b^2$ divides $N(1)=1$, hence $b=0$ and $a=\pm 1$.

**Consequences.** A nonzero element $a\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has only finitely many divisors.

Therefore, if $a\neq 0$, then there are only finitely many principal ideals that properly contain $a$, and so any ascending chain of ideals must stabilize.

(Fact 2 is technically unnecessary, but this shows that in fact there are only finitely many elements $b$ such that $(a)\subseteq (b)$, which simplifies the argument)

Comment: Basically we are using the fact that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a FD. Thanks  lot!